# What would be a constraint for "any array"?

Tags: typescript

What constraint is necessary to check that a type must be an array, whatever it's element type might be ?

The following code fails :

```js
function test<A extends any[]>(): A {
    const array: any[] = [1, 2]
    return array;
}
```

The error is a constraint error :

```
Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'A'.
  'any[]' is assignable to the constraint of type 'A', but 'A' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'any[]'.(2322)
```

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=5&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygHgIKJQD1TABM1EBDMATwG0BdAPgAoBKALkVwG8AoRfxBAQYKAJ1HkqHSrTqIAvIhoBGADSIATHT4DRKKCFFJy4yQG4eAXx48gA).

Comment: `test<A extends any>(): A[]`

Comment: Although I don't know why you need a generic here it seems to just `test(): any[]`

Comment: The example of course doesn't make sense. I have a more complex practical use case, this is just a minimal form.

Anyway, your solution works, thank you, but I don't know why.

Comment: Because your generic `A` is constrained and you need an array of `A` types.

Comment: Okay, but what's the difference with my first shot ? Why does it fail ?